# Angular2: Update UI after sending API call

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm building a UI with Angular (2) and I need the project details view to make a call to the API to get the latest data for the project every time the user interacts with the UI.
I.e. when deleting a task or marking a task as done for a project (with an API call), the project endpoint should be called again to get the latest data.

I thought I cracked it with the code below, but what actually happens in chronological order is:

1. The OPTIONS call for the GET project call is made.
2. The GET call for the project is made.
3. The DELETE call is made for a task.

This means that the project is loaded again just **BEFORE** the changes when it should be that the project is loaded just **AFTER** the changes are made.

This is the code for my project-detail.component.ts:

```
public getProject(): void {
    this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this.projectService.getProject(+params['id']))
    .subscribe(project => this.project = project);

}    

public deleteTask(task): void {
    this.projectService
        .deleteTask(task, this.project)
        .subscribe(
            this.getProject()
        );
}
```

and this is the code for the project.service.ts:

```
public getProject(id: number): Promise<Project> {
    const url = `${this.projectsURL}/${id}`;

    return this.http.get(url)
              .toPromise()
              .then(response => response.json() as Project)
              .catch(this.handleError);
}

public deleteTask(task: Task, project: Project): any {
    const url = `${this.projectsURL}/${project.id}/tasks/${task.id}`;

    return this.http.delete(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then(() => task)
        .catch(this.handleError);

  }
```

Comment: pls add code of `projectService`

Comment: Thanks, done! @Dhyey

Answer (score 0):

In `project-detail.component.ts` you should use `then` instead of `subscribe` as you are returning a `Promise` and not an `Observable`.

```
public deleteTask(task): void {
    this.projectService
        .deleteTask(task, this.project)
        .then(() => this.getProject());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I still have the issue where the GET call (step2) happens before the DELETE call (step 3)

Answer (score 0):

I would take advantage of the FlatMap operator:

```js
someMethod(){
    let obs = this.deleteTask(task).subscribe(project => this.project = project);
  }

  public getProject(): void {
    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.projectService.getProject(+params['id']))
  }

  public deleteTask(task): void {
    this.projectService
      .deleteTask(task, this.project)
      .flatMap(() => {
        return this.getProject();
      }
      );
  }
```

Hope that helps.

## Edit:

I created an angular 2 component that achieves the behaviour that you desire.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { forwardRef, Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.less']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  projectService: ProjectService;
  project: Project;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,http: Http){
    this.projectService = new ProjectService(http);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProject()
      .subscribe(project => {
        console.log(project);
        this.project = project
      });
  }

  public getProject(): Observable<any> {
    return this.route.params
      .flatMap((params) => this.projectService.getProject(+params['id']))
  }

  public delete(){
    this.deleteTask({id:1});
  }
  public deleteTask(task): void {
    this.projectService.deleteTask(task, this.project)
      .flatMap((response: any) => {
        return this.getProject();
      })
      .subscribe((project:Project)=>{
        this.project=project;
    });
  }
}

export class ProjectService {
  projectsURL = "";
  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }
  // public getProject(id: number): Observable<Project> {
  //   const url = `${this.projectsURL}/${id}`;
  //   return this.http.get(url)
  //     .map(response => response.json() as Project)
  // }

  // public deleteTask(task: Task, project: Project): Observable<any> {
  //   const url = `${this.projectsURL}/${project.id}/tasks/${task.id}`;
  //   return this.http.delete(url)
  //     .map(response => response.json())
  // }

  public getProject(id: number): Observable<Project> {
    return Observable.create(observer=>{
      console.log("Get Project");
      observer.next({id:"Project1"})
    }).delay(500);
  }

  public deleteTask(task: Task, project: Project): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer=>{
      console.log("Delete task");
      observer.next({});
    }).delay(1000);
  }
}

export class Project {
  public id: string;
}

export class Task {
  public id: string;
}
```

```html
<div >
   <button (click)="delete()">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Here is the results I see in my console:
[image]

Note that I mocked the http calls to just wait a few miliseconds and then return an object. You can use the commented methods that do the actuall http call.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I just need the call to be made so that it updates the class variable, it doesn't return anything.